# Wxpython textctrl sluggish when using SetStringItem on a loop

Tags: python, performance, forms, wxpython

In wxpython,

To update a series of items on a textCtrl widget, I am using:

```
for i in LARGELIST:
    list.SetStringItem(i, 1, str(a))
```

This works, but just like in an excel macro - which becomes sluggish if you allow it to display every single update on the screen instead of disabling it and refreshing the spreadsheet later on - I am finding the experience sluggish as each individual cell update triggers a refresh of the form.

How can I make it so that the values are only updated on the screen when the loop ends?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
window.Freeze()
for i in LARGELIST:
    list.SetStringItem(i, 1, str(a))
window.Thaw()
```

where "window" is the reference to your window